# Java I/O writing, mixingcase and getExtension problems

Tags: java, file-io, file-extension, mixed-case

I am changing names of all files in directory and if it's text file I am changing the content but it doesn't seem to work the name of the file is changed right but content is blank/gone heres is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

public class FileOps {
    public static File folder = new File(
            "C:\\Users\\N\\Desktop\\New folder\\RenamingFiles\\src\\renaming\\Files");
    public static File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {
        toUpperCase();
    }

    public static void toUpperCase() throws FileNotFoundException {
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                String newname = mixCase(listOfFiles[i].getName());

                if (listOfFiles[i].renameTo(new File(folder, newname))) {
                    String extension = FilenameUtils
                            .getExtension(listOfFiles[i].getName());
                    if (extension.equals("txt") || extension.equals("pdf")
                            || extension.equals("docx")
                            || extension.equals("log")) {
                        rewrite(listOfFiles[i]);

                        System.out.println("Done");
                    }

                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Nope");
            }
        }
    }

    public static String mixCase(String in) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (in != null) {
            char[] arr = in.toCharArray();
            if (arr.length > 0) {
                char f = arr[0];
                boolean first = Character.isUpperCase(f);
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    sb.append((first) ? Character.toLowerCase(arr[i])
                            : Character.toUpperCase(arr[i]));
                    first = !first;
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void rewrite(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath());
        BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(reader);

        try {
            FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter(file.getAbsolutePath());
            BufferedWriter outw = new BufferedWriter(fwriter);
            while (inFile.readLine() != null) {
                String line = mixCase(inFile.readLine());
                outw.write(line);
            }
            inFile.close();
            outw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cant read *docx* nor *pdf* as regular text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is several issue with your code:

1. Your `rewrite` function is perform on old name `File`. It should be done on the renamed `File`:

   ```
       String newname = mixCase(listOfFiles[i].getName());
       File renamedFile = new File(folder, newname);
       if (listOfFiles[i].renameTo(renamedFile )) {
           String extension = FilenameUtils
                   .getExtension(listOfFiles[i].getName());
           if (extension.equals("txt") || extension.equals("pdf")
                   || extension.equals("docx")
                   || extension.equals("log")) {
               rewrite(renamedFile);

               System.out.println("Done");
           }

       }
   ```
2. you are trying to read *docx* and *pdf* file like regular text file. This cannot work. You will have to use external library like [POI](http://poi.apache.org/) and [pdf Box](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)
3. Your `rewrite` function is not safe. You must unsure to close the ressources:

   ```
    FileReader reader = null;
    BufferedReader inFile = null;

   try {
   reader = new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath());
   inFile = new BufferedReader(reader);
   FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter(file.getAbsolutePath());
   BufferedWriter outw = new BufferedWriter(fwriter);

   while (inFile.readLine() != null) {
       String line = mixCase(inFile.readLine());
       outw.write(line);
   }

   } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   }finally
   {
      if(infile != null)
      inFile.close();

      if(reader != null)
      reader .close();
   }
   ```

Comment: It doesnt do anything in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can't re-write a file on top of itself.  you need to write the new content to a new file, then rename again.

Comment: Can you post and example please ? And also when I write on new file what happent to the original file?